# android - Adding an Action search bar in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, fragment, searchbar

I’m trying to add a SearchView in the ActionBar of a Fragment which is a part of DrawerLayout. I need the SearchView only for one fragment. I do the following in the onCreateOptionsMenu() method of the Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
menu.clear();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.alarm_list_menu, menu);
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
}
```

mSearchView is null every time. Have I missed some thing? I ‘m able to see the search icon on the ActionBar, but nothing more can be done.

Comment: shouldn't you do mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView(); ?

Comment: it's the same thing ! , but the problem I have in my public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
     Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), newText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     return true;
 }

 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
     Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextSubmit");
     return false;
 }

Comment: Do you have search view in menu.xml?

Comment: Yes , absolutely  <item
       android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
       android:icon="@drawable/bt_search"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="Search" />